# The equivalent code for RenderComponentPresentation() in .net or C sharp TBB

Tags: 2011, templating

I have a page template that uses a following template building block to extract components from a page.

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" --> 
                @@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

I want to write same sort of code in C sharp.

```
            var session = engine.GetSession();
            var uri = package.GetValue("Component.ID");
            Page page = (Page)session.GetObject(package.GetValue("Page.ID"));
            foreach (var cp in page.ComponentPresentations)
            {
                ///
            }
```

Can some help me to proceed further.

Answer (score 5):

The following c# TBB provides the same functional result as the DWT sample you include.

```cs
[TcmTemplateTitle("Render All Component Presentations")]
public class RenderAllComponentPresentations : ITemplate
{
    public void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
    {
        Page page = (Page)engine.GetObject(package.GetByName(Package.PageName));
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (CP cp in page.ComponentPresentations)
        {
            output.Append(engine.RenderComponentPresentation(cp.Component.Id, cp.ComponentTemplate.Id));
        }
        package.PushItem(Package.OutputName, package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Html, output.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I was actually searching for sample page TBB.

Comment: Was this answer helpful as a *sample page TBB*, or were you looking for something else? It looks like a good page-level example to me, but maybe I'm missing something. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.RenderComponentPresentation()`

```
public virtual string RenderComponentPresentation(
    TcmUri componentUri,
    TcmUri componentTemplateUri
)
```

This is exposed by the Engine class, so in a template it would be `engine.RenderComponentPresentation()`